# excelViewResolver not working when using java based configuration with spring mvc 4

Tags: spring-mvc, apache-poi

I have the requirement to display a document in excel format in my spring mvc application. I have added excelViewResolver to my AppConfig but unable to process the excel file. Please help.

Following is the AppConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.testapps.myapps")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
private static final String autowire = null;

/*
 * Configure ContentNegotiationManager
 */
    @Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.ignoreAcceptHeader(true).defaultContentType(
            MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
}

/*
 * Configure ContentNegotiatingViewResolver
 */
@Bean
public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
    ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
    resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);

    // Define all possible view resolvers
    List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<ViewResolver>();

    resolvers.add(jspViewResolver());
    resolvers.add(excelViewResolver());

    resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
    return resolver;
}


/*
 * Configure View resolver to provide XLS output using Apache POI library to
 * generate XLS output for an object content
 */
@Bean(name="excelView")
public ViewResolver excelViewResolver() {
    System.out.println("inside view resolver for excel");
    return new ExcelViewResolver();
}

/*
 * Configure View resolver to provide HTML output This is the default format
 * in absence of any type suffix.
 */
@Bean
public ViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public StandardServletMultipartResolver resolver() {
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
  }

 }
```

WebAppInitializer.java

```
 public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

 @Override
 protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
 return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
 }

 @Override
 protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
 return null;
 }

 @Override
 protected String[] getServletMappings() {
 return new String[] { "*.html" };
 }

 @Override
  protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic     registration) {
 registration.setMultipartConfig(getMultipartConfigElement());
 }

 private MultipartConfigElement getMultipartConfigElement() {
 MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement( LOCATION, MAX_FILE_SIZE, MAX_REQUEST_SIZE, FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD);
 return multipartConfigElement;
 }

private static final String LOCATION = "C:/TESTdevelopments/files/"; //      Temporary location where files will be stored

 private static final long MAX_FILE_SIZE = 5242880; // 5MB : Max file size.
                                            // Beyond that size spring will throw exception.
 private static final long MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 20971520; // 20MB : Total request size containing Multi part.

 private static final int FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD = 0; // Size threshold    after which files will be written to disk
 }
```

ExcelBuilder.java

```
 public class ExcelBuilder extends AbstractXlsxView {

private static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);

@Override
protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model,
                                  Workbook workbook,
                                  HttpServletRequest request,
                                  HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    // change the file name
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"my-xlsx-file.xlsx\"");

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Course> courses = (List<Course>) model.get("courses");

    // create excel xls sheet
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Spring MVC AbstractXlsxView");

    // create header row
    Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
    header.createCell(0).setCellValue("ID");
    header.createCell(1).setCellValue("Name");
    header.createCell(2).setCellValue("Date");

    // Create data cells
    int rowCount = 1;
    for (Course course : courses){
        Row courseRow = sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
        courseRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(course.getId());
        courseRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(course.getName());
        courseRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(DATE_FORMAT.format(course.getDate()));
    }

}
}
```

ExcelViewResolver.java

```
public class ExcelViewResolver implements ViewResolver{

@Override
public View resolveViewName(String viewName, Locale locale) throws Exception {
    ExcelBuilder view = new ExcelBuilder();
    return view;
  }
```

}

and finally controller class mapping...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadExcel.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView downloadExcel() {
    // create some sample data
    List<courseRecordParams> reports = courseRegisterService.generateReportsGeneral();

    // return a view which will be resolved by an excel view resolver
    return new ModelAndView("excelView", "reports", reports);
}
```

The problem is I am not able to view the excel file. Its generating a file not found error as in `JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.` since it tries to open a nonexisting jsp.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this problem.

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer
    .favorPathExtension(true)
    .favorParameter(false)
    .ignoreAcceptHeader(true)
    .useJaf(false)
    .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
}
```

Also, I removed the excelviewresolver which was unnecessary since this is already handled by multipartviewresolver.
After this the excel file was getting generated without any problem.

Comment: @slawek please try the above solution and reply whether it solved the problem.